# Storing arbitrary metadata in SQLAlchemy column

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In SQLAlchemy, is there a way to store arbitrary metadata in an column object? For example, I want to store a flag on each column that says whether or not that column should be serialized, and then access this information via `inspect( Table ).attrs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass extra data at the `info` param in Column initializer `Column(...., info={'data': 'data'})`